# SourceTree newbie Stop Tracking / Ignore

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

I have been searching for weeks looking at responses for similar questions and can't get anything to work

I am working on an Android project with another developer.  I only want to commit/push certain files that I change.  Instead whenever I compile or even open android studio, Sourcetree wants me to commit files in .gradle, .idea,  etc...i have tried "stop tracking" but then they add those files to "staged" and expect me to commit them. I discard them instead and start all over.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Switch back to command-line just for testing, and try:

```
git rm --cached -- aFile_you_dont_want
git check-ignore -v -- aFile_you_dont_want
```

If the second command does not return anything, check if you can add `*.graddle` (for example) in a .gitignore.
Repeat then the `check-ignore` command (you don't even have to add/commit: the ignore rules apply immediately to present files)

Once that is working (meaning the files are un-tracked and ignored), you can switch back to SourceTree.